# Why isn't anything being drawn to the JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, repaint, 2d-games

When i run my code, I should have a rectangle pop up at the top of the screen. This is my code.

```
package game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends JFrame{
    Shapes shapes = new Shapes();
    static Long lastshapemake;
    boolean running = true;
    int count = 0;
    String color;
    public static int RotationIndex = 0;

Game(){
    setSize(200, 400);
    setTitle("Tetris");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable r = new IsKeyPressed();
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
    Game game = new Game();
    game.run(game);
}

public void run(Game game) {
    shapes.newshape();
    while(true) {
        lastshapemake = System.nanoTime();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double Target_FPS = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / Target_FPS;
        double delta = 0;
        while(running) { 
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1) {
                tick();

                game.repaint();
                delta--;

            }

        }    
    }
}

public static void rotate() {
    System.out.println('h');
    RotationIndex++;
    RotationIndex %= 4;
}
void tick() {
    if(shapes.list.get(shapes.list.size() - 1).arr[RotationIndex][1] == 180){//if current shapes lowest rectangle(always the fourth) touches ground
        lastshapemake = System.nanoTime();
        shapes.newshape();
    }
}




@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    for(Rectangles emp: shapes.list) {
        g.setColor(emp.color);
        //Loop through all rectangle objects
            //Loop through each objects array
            for(int i = 0; i < 7; i += 2) {
                g.drawRect(emp.arr[RotationIndex][i], emp.arr[RotationIndex][i + 1], 20, 20);
                g.fillRect(emp.arr[RotationIndex][i], emp.arr[RotationIndex][i + 1], 20, 20);
        }}      
}
```

}

Nothing is being drawn to the screen and i don't know why. It was working before i added in super.paint(g) before drawing the rectangles, but i need to call super.paint(g) to clear the rectangles before drawing in the new ones. I don't know have to fix this so that the rectangles are still being cleared and then drawn.Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is generally helpful to use a debugger or just `System.out.println` to print the values sent to `drawRect` and `fillRect` and check if the particular code is executed at all and with which arguments.

Comment: I suggest to set up `setPreferredSize;`. Only setting `setSize` is not enough, in my personal experience.

Comment: @MichaelButscher i have and the values are definitely within the frame and the code(The drawRect lines) are definitely executed.

Comment: @RafaelPalomino It says the method setPreferredSize requires a parameter of (Dimension) not int, int

Comment: @OnEdgeGaming Then create a `new Dimension` with your required values, you get the point. Sorry the mistake.

Comment: It was working then I added super.paint(g) and then it stopped working.

Comment: @RafaelPalomino ok I’ll do that but I’ve had to leave my house so I’ll do that when I get back. I don’t understand how that will fix the problem though since the dimensions of the screen haven’t changed from when it was working to now

Comment: @RafaelPalomino I've changed it to preferred size and it changes nothing

Comment: Did you find out the solution? Can you post your `Shapes` and `Rectangles` classes?